# ACE TAO build for vxworks 6.8 (cross compiling from Windows 7 for PPC32 target)

Tags: cross-compiling, vxworks, ace, tao

Are there clear instructions to build ACE and TAO libraries for use on Windriver VxWorks OS? The goal is to build ACE TAO for RPC style communication between VxWorks and Windows machine. I am using Windriver Workbench 3.2 on windows 7, target is vxworks 6.8 ppc32.

Answer (score 0):

The only public instructions we have are part of the ACE-INSTALL.html which you can find in the root in the ACE package and we have some generic additional instructions as part of the [CORBA Programmers Guide](http://www.remedy.nl/opensource/corbapg.html).